# how I can use belongsTo with Laravel

Tags: laravel

I follow tutorial https://nick-basile.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-laravel-nova
 what I found in web and try create Post form with nova
When trying to create nev post I get message: Class 'App\Nova\BelongsTo' Not found.

How I can add the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Refer This Documentation,

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/relationships.html#belongsto

```
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\BelongsTo;

BelongsTo::make('User')
```

Comment: Thanks wery much... Now I feel myself litle stupid ;)